# IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id - on app restart

Tags: android, android-fragments

My app is built using fragments and the v4 support fragment manager. The app works well from startup and in fact I can't recreate this bug myself, so in principle the structure of my xml is fine. However my crash reports are indicating a lot of users are getting a crash when returning to the app, resuming it after a pause. I get:

```
IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f06002d
```

Please refer to my XML below. The id reported as not found can vary, it can be any one of the nested RelativeLayouts. Why are these views disappearing/not found, randomly?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F7F5F5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/menuLayout"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomFragmentLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/whenLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomFragmentLayout"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menuLayout"
    android:visibility="invisible" >

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/howLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomFragmentLayout"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menuLayout"
    android:visibility="invisible" >

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/whereLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomFragmentLayout"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menuLayout"
    android:visibility="invisible" >

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- The bottom bar -->
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomFragmentLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#999999" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit: Full stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.android/com.myapp.android.activity.MainFragmentActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f060030 (com.myapp.android:id/howLayout) for fragment WhatFragment{4220b058 #4 id=0x7f060030 WhatFragment}
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3692)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f060030 (com.myapp.android:id/howLayout) for fragment WhatFragment{4220b058 #4 id=0x7f060030 WhatFragment}
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
   at com.myapp.android.activity.MainFragmentActivity.onStart(MainFragmentActivity.java:449)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1164)
   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5114)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3692)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Do you have by chance a more complete crash report? Thanks.

Comment: Just edited and added stack trace, thanks.

Comment: Same problem here -- this crash doesn't happen for me but I keep seeing it in the submitted crash logs in the Google developer console. I'm not using the support library. Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way
1. when you gave other layout reference like android:layout_above="@+id/bottomFragmentLayout" so here "+" sign removed from reference "+" is for new id declaration so we not declare new id but just gave already define id reference.
2. in your xml define bottom layout at last and try using this layout id before bottom layout declaration that y it's not finding such kind of layout so you have decalre first layout then gave reference as another layouyt which i correct in my ans.     

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F7F5F5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomFragmentLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#999999" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/menuLayout"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomFragmentLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:visibility="visible" >

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/whenLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomFragmentLayout"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/menuLayout"
        android:visibility="invisible" >

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/howLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomFragmentLayout"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/menuLayout"
        android:visibility="invisible" >

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/whereLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomFragmentLayout"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/menuLayout"
        android:visibility="invisible" >

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's addressing my issue?

Comment: But how is that going to affect things? Please explain why this would make a difference, particularly as the app works fine in most occasions.

Comment: That's interesting - I hadn't noticed (or realised) that was a mistake in saying `layout_above="@+id/bottomLayout"` when it should be `layout_above="@id/bottomLayout"` - even though it's wrong it seems to work, so I wonder what effect that has, if any?